# Loopback post request cannot filter and array

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs

I have a `POST` road that received an `array` of `Queue`. I want to filter them before to create them inside my data source.

I tried to do it like this:

```js
  async createarraywithcheck(
    @requestBody(/*...*/)
    queues: [Omit<Queue, 'id'>],
  ): Promise<Queue[]> {
    queues = queues.filter(queue => queue.title.length < 10); //error here
    return this.queueRepository.createAll(queues);
}
```

But I get this error:

```js
Type 'Pick<Queue, "getId" | "getIdObject" | "toJSON" | "toObject" | "title">[]' 
is not assignable to type 
'[Pick<Queue, "getId" | "getIdObject" | "toJSON" | "toObject" |"title">]'.

Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)
```

I do not understand the difference, to me they are both array of `Pick<Queue, ....>`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: What line is the error coming from? My guess it's because of type of `queues` argument? Shouldn't that be `queues: Omit<Queue, 'id'>[]` ?

Comment: I add the error line (sry).
Yes !! You guessed right. But what is the difference between `Omit<Queue, 'id'>[]` and `[Omit<Queue, 'id'>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, problem comes from the type of your `queues` argument.

You set the type as `[Omit<Queue, 'id'>]`, which is [a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple). Not any tuple, but a tuple with exactly one argument.

In javascript, a tuple is basically an array. If you filter this array, what happens if none of the items pass the condition? well, you return an empty array.
Since you are re-assigning to `queues`, you may be doing the following:

```
queues = [] // here you have the error
```

Solution is one of the below:

1. `const filteredQueues: Omit<Queue, 'id'>[] = queues.filter(queue => queue.title.length < 10)`
2. `queues: Omit<Queue, 'id'>[]`

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my problem